# How to change font color of entire cell with Apache poi XSSF?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

I want to change the font color of an entire cell to an exact RGB color without changing other font styles on the text such as Bold, Italic, Underline, font size, etc.

This is the current implementation where I iterate over each cell in the excel document:

```
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.getXssfWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.getXssfWorkbook().createFont();
        font.setColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 128, 128)));
        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
            cell.setCellValue(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
        }
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

However, it does not fully work! Sometimes it does not change the font color of the entire text in the cell, it seems like it only changes the first "run" of the sharedString value.

Example:

[image]

Edit:
When checking "cell.getRichStringCellValue().numFormattingRuns()" on each cell, the cells that I fail to modify the font color on, are >1.

Any assistance in this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check if the cell contains 2+ rich text runs, and reset it to a single simple string if it does?

Comment: So, after checking that value, it looks like when it is >1 it does not change the font color. How do I reset it to single simple string?

Comment: Something like `cell.setCellValue(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString())` ought to do it